# Getting multiple HighCharts from one call

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I try to get multiple HighCharts using one function call. But it seems I can get one at a time. Every time I refresh my page, it shows a different one.

```
    var request9 = $.ajax({
    url:path,
    type:'get',
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,
    success:function (data) {
        var results = [];
        for (x = 0; x < data.total_rows; x++) {
            <CODE>
        }
        createChart(results,somethingElse);
    }        
});     
    function makeChart(info1,info2){
     Highcharts.chart ......
    }
```

Tried making call1 and call2 as two separate function calls, but I get the same result. Does someone know, why I am not getting all the graphs at once?

Comment: What does `makeChart` do?

Comment: it has the code from HichCharts to create a chat

Comment: We don't have enough info to help here.  But, my guess is that you are sending them all to the same div and it's whatever Ajax call returns last that wins.  If that's not true, show us how you are setting saveInfo1 and saveInfo2 and what happens in makeChart.

Comment: yes, you are guessing correctly. But how could I fix it?

Comment: okey I have improved my code now, you can see my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `makeChart` function in other way. I mean that you can create every new chart container basing on number of charts passed to your function. Please take a look at code below:

HTML file:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="charts"></div>
```

function definition:

```
var makeCharts = function(charts) {
    // Generate chart for each configuration
    charts.forEach((conf, i) => {
    // Create new container for chart, and append it to #charts div
    let chart = document.createElement('div')
    chart.setAttribute('id', 'container'+i)
    document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(chart)

    // Generate chart
    Highcharts.chart('container'+i, conf)
  })

}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/hw571nkg/

Best regards!